# Scaling a Grails + Hibernate app beyond a single machine

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails

I'm a total newb to Grails + Hibernate, so my apologies if this is well-known thing.

I'm doing some work on a Grails app that needs to scale pretty high, almost certainly beyond a single node.  It's using Hibernate on PostgreSQL, and I want to know if multiple Grails instances can all talk to the same Hibernate / Postgres DB at the same time (and I mean the same DB, not the same *DB server*), or each Grails instance needs its own DB (much like two CoreData-based apps couldn't access the same CoreData DB at the same time).

Is there anything built into Hibernate to handle being used as the datastore for multiple running apps at the same time?  I realise that this sounds a bit like wishful thinking, but I just want to confirm that it definitely doesn't work before moving on.

If anyone has suggestions as to what the typical approach for scaling Grails apps beyond a single instance is, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing too much about clustering, I'm successfully using two server instances running Tomcat with grails, accessing one MySQL DB on another server. The application instances both point to the same URL in the DataSource.groovy configuration.

So far I've not experienced any problems with grails or Hibernate in this regard.

Comment: Thanks .. I suspect that whether or not this works depends largely on the types of writes you're doing to the DB and whether or not there are conflicts, so there is some app-specific stuff to consider here.  Glad to know that it is at least possible.

Answer (score 6):

See this post about clustering Grails: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/07/20/basic-tomcat-clustering-grails-applications which is based on earlier work that I did and wrote about here: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=244

Comment: Hi Burt - thanks very much for the link.  I read through the whole post, and the part that interested me was the bit about session replication across multiple Tomcat servers right near the end.  I assume that this means Hibernate is happy for two Grails instances to be using a single DB concurrently at least as far as session management goes.  Does this apply to the rest of the data model as well, or is this a special replication behaviour that applies to sessions only, but not to the rest of the persistent data?

Comment: HTTP Session replication and app data replication are usually completely unrelated. This is mostly because you really should minimize HTTP session size (stateless is best) but will want to replicate whatever's there (auth info, etc.) But you want to cache application data to avoid database hits, and Hibernate 2nd-level caching is good for that. Using a distributed cache is needed when using multiple web servers.